# ¿Cómo puedo borrar todas las sesiones de Apache en Ubuntu?

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

Cómo puedo borrar o eliminar todas las sesiones de Php en Apache Ubuntu para deslogear a todos los que estén en mi página?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se pueden cerrar todas las sesiones que estén activas en apache borrando el contenido de la carpeta *SESSIONS* que en Ubuntu se encuentra en /var/lib/php/sessions con el comando:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/php/sessions/*
```

Si este comando no funciona, también se puede borrar el directorio y volverlo a crear:

```
sudo rm -R /var/lib/php/sessions
sudo mkdir /var/lib/php/sessions
sudo chmod -R 733 /var/lib/php/sessions
```

Comment: Uhms, ¿y sí Apache está escribiendo en el archivo? Si te lo cargas puede quedar algún inodo allí colgado.

Comment: Al momento de borrar la carpeta session, apache no puede acceder a ninguna sesión, queda inservible, así que creo que no quedaría nadie "colgado"

Comment: Interesante. La verdad es que necesitaría probarlo para verificar, los administradores de sistemas solemos ser muy celosos con los ficheros colgados :) ¡Gracias por compartir tus conocimientos!